# Programmatic Access to OneNote stored in Enterprise SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, onenote, onenote-api

The company I work in has a OneNote notebook stored in the organization SharePoint site.

I'll like to write an app that periodically accesses that notebook and do some processing on the content of it.

All the example code I've found authenticate with a user using OAuth.

Is there an example of how to authenticate as an app, not a user, and how to access the content of the OneNote notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can have authenticate via application-only permissions. The app will still need to be authorized by your SharePoint tenant, but after that it shouldn't require oauth.

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2017/02/09/the-onenote-rest-api-now-supports-application-level-permissions/

MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-auth-appperms

Comment: Thanks. Any chance for ready made example code? Any language will do